# run script bash when usb mouse was input

Tags: linux, bash

hy , i want to make simple bash script. 
if my usb mouse was inserted automatically run script that can disable my touchpad , and if my usb mouse was removed run script that can enable my tochpad.

this script (disabled touchpad) run when my usb mouse was inserted

> sudo modprobe -r psmouse

this script (enabled touchpad) run when my usb mouse was removed

> sudo modprobe psmouse

but where this script i put on my linux system , that can automatically run when my usb device insert/remove?

Comment: Your question is probably more appropriate for the StackExchange sites [**Super User**](http://superuser.com/) or [**Unix & Linux**](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: A way to do this would be to create a acpi event and attach the code to it. Check this out: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/acpid

Comment: as mentioned, wrong corner here, plus a duplicate in the right corner: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65891/how-to-execute-a-shellscript-when-i-plug-in-a-usb-device